# iOS Sinch VoIP Push Notification failed

Tags: ios, voip, sinch, callkit, pushkit

I am using Sinch for my iOS app's call feature. 
App is working fine when app is in foreground but not working when app is in background or closed.
I am using CallKit + SinchManagedPush together. 
I was able to get CallKit screen when app is closed for the incoming call only one time.
After that, It's not working again.

Here are the logs for the push failed.

`[http] REQUEST 3: Response status code: 200, body: {"Result":20054117,"Message":"PushFailed"}`

`push] api request to send push notifications failed:Error(code: 4000, domain: api, message: PushFailed (20054117), data: {serverCode: 20054117, serverMessage: PushFailed})`

I've tried to research about this but was not able to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I really need your help, please replay

Comment: Solved - Need to upload VoIP certificate to Sinch dashboard and use VoIP configuration in app.